# return an object with similar structured but filtered

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I have the following object:

```
const myObject = {
"-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": Object {
  "first": "Breanna",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": Object {
  "first": "Joshua",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": Object {
  "first": "Joziah",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": Object {
  "first": "Lino",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": Object {
  "first": "Rebecca",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_": Object {
  "first": "Rosario",
  "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxIB_YTBF8liL855": Object {
  "first": "Alissa",
  "last": "Blah",
}
}
```

then I have a set with the following:

```
const mySet = {
  "-Lz8YxMp-V0TfiwrkM49",
  "-Lz8YxNQP2WkkO0qpkRJ",
  "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
  "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
  "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
  "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
  "-Lz8YxOFpVHx2xPI1mUu",
  "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
  "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
  "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1",
  "-Lz8YxOI4qszJvZhrSde",
  "-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_",
}
```

I need to return myObject with ONLY the objects that match an item in mySet.
I have done this with a map but it turns myObject into an array.
The following uses map and returns an array which I can't use for this particular situation.

```
// const addGroupMembers = Object.entries(members)
//   .filter(([key]) => {
//     eachHit++;
//     console.log(key)
//     return attendanceGroupMembers.has(key);
//   })
//   .map(([_, members]) => {
//     eachHit++;
//     console.log('in map')
//     return members;
//   });
```

I would like to retain the myObject structure but with only the items found.  Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could convert `myObject` into an array of entries using [`Object.entries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) then use [`Set.has()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set/has) along with [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), and finally use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) to convert the filtered array of entries back into an object:

```js
const myObject = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn": { first: "Breanna", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": { first: "Joshua", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": { first: "Joziah", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": { first: "Lino", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": { first: "Rebecca", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_": { first: "Rosario", last: "Blah" },
    "-Lz8YxIB_YTBF8liL855": { first: "Alissa", last: "Blah" },
};

const mySet = new Set([
    "-Lz8YxMp-V0TfiwrkM49",
    "-Lz8YxNQP2WkkO0qpkRJ",
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
    "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
    "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
    "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
    "-Lz8YxOFpVHx2xPI1mUu",
    "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
    "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
    "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1",
    "-Lz8YxOI4qszJvZhrSde",
    "-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_",
]);

const myObjectFiltered = Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(myObject).filter(([key]) => mySet.has(key))
);

console.log(myObjectFiltered);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Sure, just use .reduce to assign to a new object:**

```
const addGroupMembers = Object.entries(myObject).filter(entry => 
mySet.has(entry[0])).reduce((accum, [k, v]) => {
accum[k] = v;
return accum;
}, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

The question is to me a bit confusing sorry, but I hope this can contribute :

Basically, in javascript, to directly change an existing object to remove an element, and not create an altered copy, you can use :

```
delete someObject[key]
```

it will change directly your Object, which will applies to everything which have it referenced.

as such :

```
const myObject = {
    "-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn":  {
    "first": "Breanna",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO": {
    "first": "Joshua",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE": {
    "first": "Joziah",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5": {
    "first": "Lino",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX": {
    "first": "Rebecca",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_": {
    "first": "Rosario",
        "last": "Blah",
},
"-Lz8YxIB_YTBF8liL855": {
    "first": "Alissa",
        "last": "Blah",
}
}

const mySet = [
    "-Lz8YxMp-V0TfiwrkM49",
    "-Lz8YxNQP2WkkO0qpkRJ",
    "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX",
    "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU",
    "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH",
    "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3",
    "-Lz8YxOFpVHx2xPI1mUu",
    "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT",
    "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4",
    "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1",
    "-Lz8YxOI4qszJvZhrSde",
    "-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_",
]

for (const i in myObject)
    if (!mySet.includes(i))
        delete myObject[i];

console.log(myObject);
```

An example case. Sorry for changing the syntax but it looks weird, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

using `Array#reduce` and computed property names:

```js
const yourObject={"-Lz8YxHiwp8QZW3TqAFn":{first:"Breanna",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxHqQXWoaGOFRLrO":{first:"Joshua",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxHsMItaaTVNyQRE":{first:"Joziah",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxHwuVBMWl0Go6C5":{first:"Lino",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX":{first:"Rebecca",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_":{first:"Rosario",last:"Blah"},"-Lz8YxIB_YTBF8liL855":{first:"Alissa",last:"Blah"}};

const yourSet = ["-Lz8YxMp-V0TfiwrkM49", "-Lz8YxNQP2WkkO0qpkRJ", "-Lz8YxHy0S-QkDaE1PkX", "-MmFNgjyopU3E8z5g-zU", "-Lz8YxLVi_uZp_RkcRIH", "-MuEgimJOIbPw3GyKBJ3", "-Lz8YxOFpVHx2xPI1mUu", "-Lz8YxJ-_wuk8bmEyvGT", "-Lz8YxKj5WXY1oNwylQ4", "-Lz8YxN87U1YM6_fKgq1", "-Lz8YxOI4qszJvZhrSde", "-Lz8YxI5IItUiXX6rFn_"];

let result = yourSet.reduce((acc, e, i) => {
  if (Object.keys(yourObject).includes(e))
    acc = { ...acc, [e]: yourObject[e]}
  return acc
}, {})

console.log(result)
```